# Why was my answer to a question about the naming of oozes deemed "not an answer"?

Tags: support, specific-question, answers, deleted-answers

I recently answered the question [What's the difference between a jelly, a pudding, and other oozes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/175307/whats-the-difference-between-a-jelly-a-pudding-and-other-oozes/) by saying that there is no answer to discover. However, [my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/175307/whats-the-difference-between-a-jelly-a-pudding-and-other-oozes/175311#175311) was deleted. That's fine in and of itself, but I'm curious as to why.

The only reason I could find in the comments was a claim that it doesn't answer the question. This puzzles me. I mean, I admit it's not the best answer I've ever written; it could do with some more sources to back it up, and I can imagine it being disappointing to someone hoping for a clearly-detailed taxonomy of puddings. But the question was "What's the difference between a jelly, an ooze, and a pudding," and the answer was "there isn't any clearly defined taxonomy so the names are just arbitrary." That *seemed*  to answer to the question, to me.

I was evidently wrong about that, but I don't understand how I was wrong. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: For reference, I have now undeleted the answer as I agree that is was a legitimate answer, although a little lacking in support.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## Unsupported answers may be deleted

I had voted to delete because while your initial argument on there  not being an explanation was reasonable, the remaining part about what you suspect may be going on was completely unsupported conjecture. As likely as it may be, it was just a guess.

At times, that can be resolved by adding a Moderator provided notice to add support or the answer may be deleted.

Other times, the community agrees that without support, it can be deleted.

In this case, some community members agreed and others did not.